# Firefox float behaves differently then in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website, and have floated an image to the right of a div with some text to the left, which I have done many times before. However for some reason, the image is not floating completely over to the right in FF, but is in Chrome and IE/Edge. It's probably something really obvious, but any insight?

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome/IE**

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.chriswickham.co.uk/gohard/img/workouts/hammer_curl.png" height="85%" style="float:right;padding-left:40px"/>
    <h1>Hammer Curl</h1>
    <h2>Arms</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dignissim ut mauris in vehicula. Suspendisse sodales nec quam in convallis. In quis ante eros. Pellentesque id lacus et massa tempor hendrerit.</p>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 1000px;
   padding: 20px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Your code renders identically on Firefox and Chrome. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group your text and title elements together, and provide them a width.

From the snippet you supplied, it looks like both screenshots are actually obeying the rules you've supplied - both are floating the image to the right of your text.

However, there's no specification of how far over it should be -- just how far from the text (40px padding-left) and how large the ENTIRE item should be ("wrapper" @ 1000px);

Try this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.chriswickham.co.uk/gohard/img/workouts/hammer_curl.png" height="85%" style="float:right;padding-left:40px"/>
    <div class="content">
       <h1>Hammer Curl</h1>
       <h2>Arms</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dignissim ut mauris in vehicula. Suspendisse sodales nec quam in convallis. In quis ante eros. Pellentesque id lacus et massa tempor hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    width: 700px // or whatever you want to set it to
}
```

By wrapping the non-image elements together, and specifying a width for them specifically, you should be able to keep the experience the same across most browsers.

EDIT: Fixed some formatting.

Comment: I understand :) I don't have access to my computer at the moment, but I'll give this a try when I am. Is there any particular reason why FF behaves differently in this instance?

Comment: I think the problem is more that there's not a specific way it's "supposed" to behave, without a set width. It's up to the browser manufacturer to decide what their defaults are in the absence of other specification.

Comment: "*there's no specification of how far over it should be*". See [Here are the precise rules that govern the behavior of floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules)

Comment: @Oriol true, but that's more about relative positioning vs width of elements. Both browsers in OP's example are obeying the spec.